# Finding width of a slit in diffraction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

$500nm$ light is illuminating an aperture of width
$$d_1=0.2mm$$ The diffracted light from this first aperture then illuminates a second aperture $1m$ away. What is the smallest width, $d_2$, of the second aperture that will allow most of the diffracted light cone to pass through it?

I have tried to solve it, even checking my notes for the lecture
[image]

[image]

I could not find information to help to solve this problem. I have tried to utilise one formula as

[image]

[image]

however 2.5mm is not the answer. How can I proceed? Thank you.

Comment: What is the given answer?

Comment: @Farcher It does not clarify in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The sketches in your solution do not match the text of the problem. The way I understood the text, it is describing what is known as Fraunhofer diffraction. Check the corresponding wikipedia article. Especially look at the first example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction#Examples . It has the solution to your question: most of the light is contained within the angle $\alpha = 2\lambda/W$, in your case $\lambda=0.5\mu m$ and $W=200\mu m$. Then the size of the central band at a distance $z=1m$ is given by $d_f = \alpha z=2\lambda/W\approx 5mm$. This is your answer: At a distance $z=1m$ the most diffracted intensity will get through a slit $d_f=5mm$ wide.